# Angular directive controller scope inheritance

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**Lets start with some code**

Html:

```
<rd-search-set type="'ActiveProfileContact'">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-static-top" role="search">
        <rds-input />
    </form>
</rd-search-set>
```

rds-input template:

```
<div class="input-group rd-search-wrap">
<div class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="{{'FIND_CONTACT' | translate | capitalize}}..." ng-modal="src.value" />
<div class="rd-search-state">
    <i class="fa spin2D fa-spinner" ng-if="src.isBusy"></i>
    <span class="text-muted rd-search-result" ng-if="!src.isBusy">{{src.amountString}}</span>
</div>
```

Javascript / AngularJs:

```
angular
    .module("App")
    .directive("rdSearchSet", rdSearchSet)
    .directive("rdsInput", rdsInput);

function rdSearchSet() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            onSearch: "=onSearch",
            searchForType: "=type",
            relatedGuids: "=rdSearchRelatedGuids",
            searchEventType: "=rdSearchEventType",
        },
        controller: "SearchController",
        controllerAs: "src",
        bindToController: true,
        replace: false,
    };

    return directive;
}

rdsInput.$inject = ["rdBaseUrl"];
function rdsInput(rdBaseUrl) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: rdBaseUrl + "Partials/Directives/Search/rdsInput.html",
        require: "^rdSearchSet",
        transclude: true,
        scope: false,
    };

    return directive;
}
```

**The problem**
I'm having alot of trouble getting / setting data on the controller of the `rdSearchSet` directive. Last thing I tried is setting the `rdsInput` directive scope property to false, hoping that I can access the parent scope values using the `controllerAs: "src"` property of `rdSearchSet`.

**My question in short:** What is the best way to access the parent directive's controller(as) scope as transparent as possible? Like, use a Directive to load html and bind to parent directive scope properties, both ways.

**EDIT:**
 I have moved the `rdSearchSet` directive html to a template that looks like this:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-static-top navbar-royal" role="search">
    <rds-input />
</form>
<rds-list />
```

```
rdSearchSet.$inject = ["rdBaseUrl"];
    function rdSearchSet(rdBaseUrl) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                onSearch: "=onSearch",
                searchForType: "=type",
                relatedGuids: "=rdSearchRelatedGuids",
                searchEventType: "=rdSearchEventType",
            },
            templateUrl: rdBaseUrl + "Partials/Directives/Search/rdsSearchSet.html",
            controller: "SearchController",
            controllerAs: "src",
            bindToController: true,
            replace: false,
        };

        return directive;
    }
```

> The problem that still exists is that I am not able to use the `ControllerAs` prefix. The
>   text input field in `rdsInput` uses a `ng-model="src.value"` but the
>   value is not set in the `rdSearchSet`'s Controller.

Comment: What's the thought behind adding this search to a directive?  Would a basic search filter not work?

Comment: @someoneHere The controller behind these directives sends requests to the server to search for data. I have to use directives since I wanted to use this in multiple scenarios.

Comment: You can define a [`link`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-) function for your `rdsInput` directive and use the fourth argument (collection of required controllers) to access the parent controller scope aliased by `controllerAs` (i.e. something like `ctrls[0].src`).

Comment: @miqid I know that would work but I dont understand how 'scope: false' would work in this scenario, because 'scope: false' does not create a new scope and inherits the parent scope. Then what am I supposed to bind the controller properties to? And why can I not access the parent controller property names without the link method?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems ... one is a simple typo for `ng-model` where you have `ng-modal`.

The other is isolated scope only works when you use a template, it doesn't work for existing html within the element.

If you move the `<form>` to a template your code will work

```
<rd-search-set></rd-search-set>
```

JS

```
function rdSearchSet() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl:'search.html',
        scope: {
            .....,
        },
        controller: "SearchController",
        controllerAs: "src"
    };

    return directive;
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/uJaulo3ZOumILgwHeapf?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: I have done that but it seems that the ControllerAs is not inherited by the child directives. Can this be done at all? I can post some code soon.

Comment: I have removed the `controllerAs: "src"` prefix in the child directive `rdsInput` and moved the `value` property to an object. This works, but I still one remaining question. It seems that the `controllerAs: "src"` can't be inherited by child directives, is this true and if so, why?

Comment: Update the demo showing where you are having issues. Not sure how you are trying to `inherit` or what it is exactly you are trying to do

Comment: Looks like I made a html syntax mistake, replaced `<rds-search />` with `<rds-search></rds-search>`. Now the event for update value, `$watch` didn't work so I chose to use `ng-keyup` in the `rdsInput` directive. [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gelAfioKY3MPGDuHvCSZ?p=preview)